# Are there limitations to JS searching by HTML ID tag based on type?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-selectors

I just did a test, and it seems like the below code will NOT find the following div `<div class="class-name" id="1">`

```
integer = 1
$('.class-name#'+integer)
```

However, when the HTML code is changed to this: `<div class="class-name" id="number-1">`, the following code will work:

```
integer = 1
$('.class-name#number-'+integer)
```

Just wondering then if ID has to start with a letter?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/70586/1209018

Comment: Can't repro btw: https://jsfiddle.net/fjx5k37h/ (assuming valid code)

Comment: @Felix Kling: That's interesting. I would expect it to fail in CSS and qSA (and it does). It looks like jQuery's implementation is a bit off.

Comment: @BoltClock: Good point. CSS identifier definition is here: https://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/syndata.html#value-def-identifier (and still seems to be used in latest CSS selector drafts).

Comment: @Felix Kling: Yeah I wouldn't bank on the grammar for basic language features ever changing :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The HTML 4.01 spec states that ID tokens must begin with a letter ([A-Za-z]) and may be followed by any number of letters, digits ([0-9]), hyphens (-), underscores (_), colons (:), and periods (.).

This restriction was removed in HTML 5.

What doctype are you using?  Perhaps jQuery is smart enough to follow the spec if you are using an older doctype?

Comment: Thanks, I didn't realize that. Can I ask where you found that source?

Comment: The HTML specs themselves document what is valid for class and id attributes.  https://www.w3.org/TR/html401/types.html#type-name states  "ID and NAME tokens must begin with a letter ([A-Za-z]) and may be followed by any number of letters, digits ([0-9]), hyphens ("-"), underscores ("_"), colons (":"), and periods (".")."